# second simultaneous 'for loop' execution break the first one

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

For over a year I used this mess to execute 'for loop' simultaneously.

```
import time

#in actual program this is a dynamic dictionary with different amount of keys/values pairs

mydict = {1: 'czech', 2: 'dutch', 3: 'English'}

def function(id):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(mydict[id])

#if you try this code, you will see 'print' for all dictionary keys
#simultaneously, despite the fact that it's a for loop with time.sleep
#the exec here creates new function with name from 'mydict' and connects
#it to a separate process

for id in mydict:
    exec("""def func""" + str(id) + """():\n  function(id)""")
    exec("""p""" + str(id) + """ = Process(target=func""" + str(id) + """)\np""" + str(id) + """.start()""")
```

But now sometimes, when other program (even with different venv) tries to execute similar code, the first program that already executing this code completely breaks. I think it's caused by 'exec' limitations, but I am not sure, since I have never seen any errors. It's just pauses or something like that. If anyone have any idea what is the problem and how it could be tweaked so several simultaneous 'for loops' execution would be possible, I would be happy to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `args` parameter to pass arguments to the target function instead of using `exec` to construct statements. You should also add `if __name__ == '__main__':` to make sure your child process doesn't execute the same code that only the parent process should.

Replace your `for` loop with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = []
    for id in mydict:
        p = Process(target=function, args=(id,))
        p.start()
        l.append(p)
    for i in l:
        i.join()
```